# iOS Programming: Access instance variables from View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller, instance-variables

I have created a custom class of NSObject, and I would like to access some instance variables from my main View Controller to that custom class, how do you do that?

EDIT: Perhaps I was unclear in my first formulation. It is the instance variables from the ViewController class I would like to access, not the ivars from my custom class.

Comment: As i understand you want to access the same class variable into different place? or what kinda value you are tying to access?

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, the simplest way is to pass view controller instance during initialization. Just implement `initWithViewController:(UIViewController*)vc` in your custom class.

Answer (score 0):

You should expose your data as properties in your `NSObject` subclass. You can find a description of properties at this tutorial: http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/properties.html.

Answer (score 0):

You should better use properties to easy access to some info in your custom class.
They automatically generate iVars.

Also you can access public (declared in .h file) ivars directly:

```
@interface CustomClass : NSObject
{
    NSArray *_array1;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *array2;



CustomClass *instance = [CustomClass new];

NSArray *a1 = instance->_array1;
NSArray *a2 = instance.array2;
```